# In MS Master Data Services does a new Version get automatically created when you commit one?

Tags: version

I'm new to MDS and haven't installed yet, just starting to read about it. I was wondering, when you commit a Version of master data, does a new version get automatically created or do you have to manually create the next version, or perhaps if there a procedure you can call to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you flag the answer you got as answer? in my opinion it is correct and exact answer.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to manually create a new version by copying an existing one. However, the version you copy must be a committed version. Here's the lifecycle of an MDS version:

1. When you create a new MDS model a version (usually called VERSION_1) is created along with it.
2. VERSION_1 is what is called an Open version. Which is to say that the data within this version is open for editing.
3. To create a new version, you must Lock VERSION_1 (use the Manage -> Versions menu under the Version Management function on the home page). Locking a version makes it read-only to all users other than the administrators.
4. You must then Validate VERSION_1 (use the Validate Version menu item in Version Management). This will apply any business rules that exist on that model on the data in that version.
5. After the version has been successfully validated (that is, all the members in the version are Valid) you need to Commit VERSION_1 (again, use the Validate Version menu item in Version Management).
6. Now that VERSION_1 is committed you can Copy it to create a new Version. The new version will be Open by default.

Note that you can have any number of versions in a model and each of them can be Open, Locked or Committed. It is even possible to Uncommit committed versions and Open them again. This might be more information than you are looking for but I figured it was worth documenting the whole Version lifecycle to really clarify things.